# Are some profiles on Facebook un-blockable?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Facebook habitually recommends some names totally out of the blue as "You may know". My stock response is to view that profile, and if it sets my spidey sense tingling - block.
Recently I moved to block a couple of such recommendation under the "You may know".

A few of these could not be blocked. After the confirmation dialog - there was no further action to redirect to the Blocking page. The Blocking page too does not mention these profiles.

These so-called unblockables appear to differ from the blockables in two ways

```
- URL carries id as a numeric value instead of alphanumeric string 
- URL ends with a "&fref=pymk" *this may be an acronym for "People you may know"*
```

For instance, [this profile](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100010927813943) and [this](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100010935582811) could not be blocked

EDIT
Following up on the posted answer below - these particular profiles appear apparently unblockable even using the Settings->Block Users. An error message dialog comes up with the string "Something's gone wrong. We're working to get it fixed as soon as we can."
UNEDIT

- Why am I unable to block *all* random profiles recommended by Facebook?
- Are some profiles on Facebook un-blockable?

Comment: Just curious, why do you wanna block people who hasn't done you any harm? There will be an infinite number of Facebook users to block with your strategy and you might by mistake block someone whom's services you might find useful in the future. Blocking is for cowards.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this happens. I don't know what is the exact reason behind this. But if you are unable to block/report someone from their timeline. You can block anyone by using block tab from your settings.

Go to **Settings** -> **Blocking**

You can block by name, email address or timeline address.

Here is the direct link -> https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking

Comment: No go. Trying that FB says "Something's gone wrong. We're working to get it fixed as soon as we can." for those profiles

Comment: Try with other browser or clean your current browser.

Comment: Tried that already :)